# Can we opinion about the list of core applications for the Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

As many others, I am excited about the coming release of the first Ubuntu Phone image.

On this page are listed the core applications that will be available on this image: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuPhone/CoreApps/](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuPhone/CoreApps/)

I wonder where can we opinion about this list. I believe that working camera and an equivalent of Google maps to use the GPS are very needed also.

Best regards,
Pierre

Answer (score 1):

You can voice your opinion and foster discussion on the [Ubuntu phone mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone). You'll simply need to:

- [Join the open Launchpad team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone/+join)
- Send an e-mail to the list

Answer (score 0):

You can start develpers page of Ubuntu [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/) :)